# Understanding how to install 14.04 on XPS 13 9343

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, touchpad, brightness

I recently got a laptop to use Ubuntu on. XPS 13 9343. I've reinstalled the OS a plethora of times because of so much difficulty between drivers, issues with touchpad, wifi, etc.

Can any explain to me what kernel I should be running, what settings I should install for the touchpad, get brightness working, etc? I've see so many conflicting resources that has given me some installation issues and would like a little bit more guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Just install Ubuntu 14.04.3. If you have any issues with your hardware you are welcome to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a [complete step-by-step guide](http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide-update/)  on how to install Ubuntu 15.04 and getting everything to work properly on the Dell XPS 13 9343.

If you are fine with Ubuntu 15.04, you can give a try. I hope it will be helpful to you.

**To resume you need to :**

1. Install Ubuntu 15.04
2. Connect your computer with a USB Wifi/Ethernet adapter and run :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```
3. Fix kernel panic on suspend issue :

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:inaddy/lp1415880
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

After that your XPS 13 should work properly.

Comment: Why do you suggest installing an unsupported kernel?

Comment: Which problems?

Comment: Why do you say unsupported kernel ? 4.1.4 is a stable kernel. What is the problem ?

Comment: kernel 4.1.4 is not supposed to be used in stable Ubuntu releases, and it will not get security updates, etc. It is not supported in Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok. Understood.